# How to use serial print for Arduino

Tags: c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I want to use `Serial.print()` for Arduino projects. The specific problem is that I want to print two numbers separated by slash like this:

`56 / 345`

I could do

```
int x = 56;
int y = 345;
Serial.print(x);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(y);
```

Can I avoid the second serial print or give only one serial print?
The API does not use `printf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an `sprintf()` to a temporary string, then `Serial.print()` that:

```
char tmp[32];  
sprintf(tmp, "%d/%d", x, y);  
Serial.print(tmp);
```

Comment: Just as an aside, it's worth also considering the performance implications of this. sprintf is *slow*. If your code is performance-critical, manually printing each section will almost certainly be faster (and use less memory).